# How to make "Chameleonic Ambiance Script" select a lighter hue for dark wallpapers?

Tags: themes, customization

I just started using an amazing script that makes the default "Ambiance" theme use that selected color.

More details can be found [Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/chameleonic-ambiance-script-matches-gtk-theme-to-your-wallpaper/)

I find this really amazing. But with my wallpaper being as shown below, the selection color, progress-bars color as after running the script are too dark (that can be seen in the following screenshot).

[image]

I've learnt that what is done is the average color from the wallpaper is selected and then its tint is used (which is always a darker tint).

So can I make this algorithm or whatever select a lighter tint of the average color??

Or can it be made to select the lightest color instead of the average color from the wallpaper??

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in `get_color(self)` function,

```
    additional_color = 70
    rgb_red = int(rgb_set[0]) + additional_color
    rgb_green = int(rgb_set[1]) + additional_color
    rgb_blue = int(rgb_set[2]) + additional_color
    if (rgb_red > 255): rgb_red = 255
    if (rgb_green > 255): rgb_green = 255
    if (rgb_blue > 255): rgb_blue = 255

    color_hex = '%02x%02x%02x' % (rgb_red, rgb_green, rgb_blue)
```

### Before :

[image]

### After :

[image]

You can change `additional_color` if you want ligher/darker color.

[Here is full script.](http://pastebin.com/bd1NMD4g)

Comment: What part of the above code makes the color go light? :o...curious..

Comment: How do you make any color lighter? by adding white color,right? here `color_hex` is hexadecimal value generated from `RGB` color. How to add white color in `RGB`? add same value in `Red,Green,Blue`. I've added `70` points in `RGB` values.

Comment: If i want to make it even lighter,i add value smaller than 70 or more than 70?

Comment: increase `additional_color` to get lighter color(maximum value is 255).e.g. try with `125`.

Comment: well its not working for somereason with me :(....with my default background being this-http://i.stack.imgur.com/nO2fd.png...the selected color always used to be #6e8703...and even after trying multiple values off additional color,its still the same... :(

Comment: Did you use above given script? for me with `additional color = 0` it is `#6e8702` and with `additional color = 70` it is `#b4cd48` for that background.

Comment: yes i copy pasted it as you said in the get_color function

Comment: you should comment out `color_hex = '%02x%02x%02x' % (int(rgb_set[0]), int(rgb_set[1]), int(rgb_set[2]))` from original script or use my modified script from pastebin. Here is my `diff` file --> http://pastebin.com/BRAkKe8f

Comment: okay i should cpy paste everything oout there? even the 28c28 thing? and there is a line after the original `color_hex...`thing...it is `return str(color_hex)`...should i remove that too?? or should i keep it intact?

Comment: to instruct this way is quite confusing to you so just use this http://pastebin.com/bd1NMD4g . If you are curious, see modifications.

Comment: @Nirmik hey, does this work for you?